# SQLite and Caching Application Block

Tags: sqlite, caching-application-block

Has anyone used the Caching Application Block with SQLite to persist data?

I'd like to get some details.

Thanks

Comment: what are you looking for when you say "some details"? Would you be more specific? Perhaps the question is too general for folks who could contribute to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
objCatch.Add("DsFromDb", ds, CacheItemPriority.Normal, null, new Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.Expirations.AbsoluteTime(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)));
```